isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations is always false even when the app has the "allow background usage" or "don't optimize" setting enabled
On most phones PowerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations() is working correctly but on a few phones the value is always false even when the user has manually selected allow background usage or don't optimize under battery settings for the app.
I suspect this means my package name has entered some list on those phones due to excessive battery usage or due to not being used much. I was able to get one of those phones to whitelist my app again running adb -d shell dumpsys deviceidle whitelist +packagename but that isn't an acceptable solution for users.
So, what are my options? Can users at least look at whatever might have put the app on that list? Can they change that somehow without using adb? The two devices I'm testing are Android 14.

Happens on Pixel 7. Any ideas why or how to get to the whitelist ?

Nope, I've never figured it out.
